# Remove all empty ArrayLists from an ArrayList with Java

Tags: java

I want to go through my ArrayList of ArrayLists and remove all the ones that are empty. Is there a fast and efficient way to do this, other then I guess a for loop?

Example Ouput:

> [ [alec, joe, ray], [], [eric, jacob], [] ]

Would then look like this:

> [ [alec, joe, ray], [eric, jacob] ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should suffice.

```
nestedArrayList = nestedArrayList.stream()
    .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

or as Zabuza has suggested, you could use `removeIf`:

```
nestedArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList::isEmpty);
```

IMHO I'd go with the second approach for a couple of reasons but most importantly reading it like *"nestedArrayList remove if ArrayList is empty"* provides better intent of the code and easier to understand.

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Actually there is no need for re-collecting everything. You could do it in-place. Also very convenient by using `List#removeIf`.

Comment: @Zabuza true, less overhead in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas above as posted by Aomine or iterator like this:

```
package com.company;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

     ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> lista = new ArrayList<>(){{
         add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
         add(new ArrayList<>());
     }};

     Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> iter = lista.iterator();

     while(iter.hasNext()){
         if (iter.next().isEmpty())
             iter.remove();
    }

        System.out.println(lista);

    }

}
```

Comment: The way you add the stuff to your list looks unusual. I mean it probably works, but it isn't easy to read.

Comment: @Zabuza It's anonymous class initialization, or known as "double brace initialization" on stackoverflow. It's a quicker way to just initialize the ArrayList.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unusual style that might confuse beginners. So I'm glad that you added the *term*.